# How to clear project cache with Doom Emacs?

Tags: projectile, doom

When add a project with path `/Users/me/folerd1/myproject`, it works well.
Use `SPC p d` to delete the added project `myproject` under `folder1` path, then add it under another path `/Users/me/folder2/myproject`. It can be shown as `/Users/me/folder2/myproject` in the `SPC p p` list. However, if select the new `myproject` in the new folder. It opened in the old folder `folder1` again.

So it seems it's using cache to fetch the same project name even under different path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Managing the projectile cache

`SPC p i` will invalidate the project cache and remove any files changes since the cache was created or added to (when ever files are opened).  Very useful when files are renamed.

`SPC p D` will read the projects on the `projectile-project-search-path` so should update the projects listed when using `SPC p p`

I use this code in the Doom `config.el` file to set the Projectile search path:

```
;; Define a project path to discover projects using SPC p D
;; https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/usage.html
;; (setq projectile-project-search-path '("~/projects/" "~/work/" ("~/github" . 1)))
(setq projectile-project-search-path '(("~/projects" . 2) ("~/.config" . 1)))
```

In this example the `~/projects` directory and its sub-directories are searched, along with the `.config` directory

#### Disable the cache

If the projectile cache causes more challenges that value it provides, then disable the cache in the Doom `config.el` file

```
;; Disable projectile cache - saves requirement to invalidate cache when moving files
;; (setq projectile-enable-caching nil)
```

Hope this helps.